# $.parseJSON with JsonConvert.SerializeObject

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3

What's the correct way of serializing .net class to json and using it in javascript ?

for example on server side we've got this:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var someClass = new SomeClass { Message = "let's try <b> this </b> and this \" " };
        ViewBag.someDataJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(someClass);
        return View();
    }

    public class SomeClass
    {
        public string Message;
    }
```

and on client side:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var someData = $.parseJSON("@Html.Raw(ViewBag.someDataJson)");
        alert(someData.Message);
    });
</script>
```

will result:

```
var someData = $.parseJSON("{"Message":"let's try <b> this </b> and this \" "}");
```

which is incorrect. Also without Html.Raw() result will also be incorrect:

```
var someData = $.parseJSON("{&quot;Message&quot;:&quot;let&#39;s try &lt;b&gt; this &lt;/b&gt; and this \&quot; &quot;}");
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is [a small blog post about doing exactly this.](http://blog.falafel.com/Blogs/basem-emara/2012/05/16/convert-a-c-object-to-javascript-in-mvc-razor)

It uses [`Json.Encode(someClass)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.json.encode%28v=vs.111%29.aspx)

```
var someData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(yourViewModelCSharpObject))
```

You'll be passing the actual object to the view, and not a JSON string representation.

Good luck!